# Pandas merge functionality in Polars

Tags: python, pandas, merge, python-polars

I want to merge two Polars DataFrames (possibly on multiple columns) with the columns used for merging not being duplicated.

Current behavior:

```
>>> a 
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> b
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 4   ┆ 4   │
│ 5   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> a.join(b, how='outer', on='a')
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ a    ┆ b    ┆ a_right ┆ b_right │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪══════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 3       ┆ 3       │
│ null ┆ null ┆ 4       ┆ 4       │
│ null ┆ null ┆ 5       ┆ 5       │
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
└──────┴──────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

What I want:

```
>>> a 
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> b
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 4   ┆ 4   │
│ 5   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> <what command goes here>
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b_x  ┆ b_y  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1.0  ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2.0  ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
│ 4   ┆ null ┆ 4.0  │
│ 5   ┆ null ┆ 5.0  │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I want this behavior as I have large DataFrames which I want to merge on multiple columns. One way that might work is to just merge the resulting key columns somehow and then remove the duplicate columns but that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `how` parameter of [`pl.DataFrame.join`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html) to `"outer_coalesce"` gives the expected dataframe.

```py
a.join(b, on="a", how="outer_coalesce").sort("a")
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ b_right │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ null    │
│ 2   ┆ 2    ┆ null    │
│ 3   ┆ 3    ┆ 3       │
│ 4   ┆ null ┆ 4       │
│ 5   ┆ null ┆ 5       │
└─────┴──────┴─────────┘
```

From the documentation:

> Same as ‘outer’, but coalesces the key columns

**Note.** The final `sort("a")` is only there to produce the expected ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer_coalesce` strategy of [`join`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html):

```py
(
    a.join(b, how='outer_coalesce', on='a', suffix='_y')
    .rename({'b':'b_x'})
    .sort('a')
)

┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b_x  ┆ b_y  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 3    ┆ 3    │
│ 4   ┆ null ┆ 4    │
│ 5   ┆ null ┆ 5    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I've also added a [`rename()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`sort()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.sort.html) to get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of join with an "outer_coalesce" join (using python polars 0.20.14 or later) which is the same as an "outer" join, except that it coalesces the index columns. For instance:

```
>>> df1 = pl.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3], b=[1,2,3]))
>>> df2 = pl.DataFrame(dict(a=[3,4,5], b=[3,4,5]))

>>> df1.join(df2, on="a", how="outer_coalesce", suffix="_y")\
       .rename({"b": "b_x"}).sort("a")

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b_x  ┆ b_y  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2    ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 3    ┆ 3    │
│ 4   ┆ null ┆ 4    │
│ 5   ┆ null ┆ 5    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```